# I'm thrilled that this scala snippet uses all of my processors to find the (correct) answer faster but... why does it do that?

Tags: scala, concurrency

So I was messing around with some easy problems to get better at scala and I wrote the following program to calculate primes using an Eratosthenes's sieve.  When I bump up the number of primes to find, I noticed that my cpu would max out during the calculation.  Now I have no clue why it's using more than 1 core and I was afraid it would muck up the answer but it appears to be correct upon multiple runs so it must not be.  I'm not using .par anywhere and most all of my logic is in for-comprehensions.

Edit: I'm using scala 2.9.1

```scala
object Main {
  val MAX_PRIME = 10000000

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Generating array")
    val primeChecks = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.fill(MAX_PRIME + 1)(true)
    primeChecks(0) = false

    println("Finding primes")
    for (
      i ← 2 to MAX_PRIME if primeChecks(i);
      j ← i * 2 to MAX_PRIME by i
    ) primeChecks(j) = false

    println("Filtering primes")
    val primes = for { (status, num) ← primeChecks.zipWithIndex if status } yield num

    println("Found %d prime numbers!".format(primes.length))

    println("Saving the primes")
    val formatter = new java.util.Formatter("primes.txt", "UTF-8")
    try {
      for (prime ← primes)
        formatter.format("%d%n", prime.asInstanceOf[Object])
    }
    finally {
      try { formatter.close } catch { case _ ⇒ }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit 2: You can use the following snippet in a REPL to get the multi-threading behavior so therefore it has to be because of the for-comprehension (at least in scala 2.9.1).

```
val max = 10000000
val t = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.fill(max + 1)(true)
for (
    i <- 2 to max if t(i);
    j <- i * 2 to max by i
) t(j) = false
```

Comment: How many cores? One core may just be the garbage collector being busy...

Comment: I have a quad core and the java process is using over 90% total cpu for (the majority of) the duration of the program's runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your code that's using multiple threads, it's the JVM that is.  What you are seeing is the GC kicking in.  If I increase MAX_PRIME to 1000000000 and give it 6Gb of Java stack to play with I can see a steady-state of 100% of 1 CPU and about 4Gb mem.  Every so often the GC kicks in and it then uses 2 CPUs.  The following Java stack trace (pruned for clarity) show what's running inside the JVM:

```
"Attach Listener" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000000d13800 nid=0xf waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000000a15000 nid=0xd runnable [0x0000000000000000]
"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000000a11800 nid=0xc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000000a0e800 nid=0xb waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000000a0d000 nid=0xa runnable [0x0000000000000000]
"Finalizer" daemon prio=3 tid=0x00000000009e7000 nid=0x9 in Object.wait() [0xffffdd7fff6dd000]
"Reference Handler" daemon prio=3 tid=0x00000000009e5800 nid=0x8 in Object.wait() [0xffffdd7fff7de000]
"main" prio=3 tid=0x0000000000428800 nid=0x2 runnable [0xffffdd7fffa3d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:76)
"VM Thread" prio=3 tid=0x00000000009df800 nid=0x7 runnable 
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=3 tid=0x0000000000438800 nid=0x3 runnable 
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=3 tid=0x000000000043c000 nid=0x4 runnable 
"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=3 tid=0x000000000043d800 nid=0x5 runnable 
"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=3 tid=0x000000000043f800 nid=0x6 runnable 
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=3 tid=0x0000000000a2f800 nid=0xe waiting on condition
```

There's only one thread (main) running Scala code, all the others are internal JVM ones.  Note in particular there's 4 GC threads in this case - that's because I'm running this on a 4-way machine and by default the JVM will allocate 1 GC thread per core - the exact setup will depend on the particular mix of platform, JVM and command-line flags that are used.

If you want to understand the details (It's complicated!), the following links should get you started:

- [Java SE 6 Performance White Paper](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/6performance.html)
- [Memory Management in the JavaHotSpot™ Virtual Machine](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf)

Comment: There is no way this is correct unless [jconsole lies about gc time](http://i.imgur.com/YNd99.png).  12 minutes of cpu time vs 1 second of gc time by running the second code snipped I posted ~11 times.  Not to mention it doesn't make any sense.  Why would it use 3 entire cores for garbage collection when 0 objects are being created?

Comment: It's absolutely correct.  I've deliberately set things up so I was running with only just enough stack for the program to run.  That puts memory pressure on the VM and the GC consequently runs harder to try to meet its goals - see the second link in my answer.  As it says:

"Having sufficient available memory is the most important factor affecting garbage collection performance."

and as I said:

"the exact setup will depend on the particular mix of platform, JVM and command-line flags that are used"

Comment: So it turns out jconsole is lying.  I was using the g1 garbage collector and it maxes out all of my cores + vastly increases the runtime even when I have waaay more memory than needed (as in gigs more) yet according to jconsole it isn't doing anything at all.  I switched to concMarkSweep and it ran several times faster with expected cpu usage.  I wrote a quick pure-java implementation just using for loops and I still find this issue with the g1 garbage collector.  Still don't even get why it would be garbage collecting in the first place since I'm just modifying an array with primitives.

Comment: You aren't modifying an array with primitives. From looking at the disassembled class files there's boxing and unboxing going on, so there is object creation/destruction happening behind the scenes.  The reason for that is explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427759/project-euler-7-scala-problem/2429672#2429672) - basically you are parameterising ArrayBuffer so it stores object references, not primitive values.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Further testing with provided jar leads to multicore usage on OSX, Java 1.6.0_26, HotSpot Server VM, Scala 2.9.1.

If you're on a *nix-based system, this will say `90%` and really only be using one core. It'll say `230%` for 100% of 2 cores and 30% of another or any variation thereof.

For this code on my machine, the CPU usage bounces between 99% and 130%, the 130% when the garbage collector is running in the background.

Comment: I'm running this on windows and it's definitely maxing out all of my cores for > 20 seconds.  I'm also using Java7 as the jre but I highly doubt that would cause it to run in parallel over Java6.  Interesting it doesn't seem to be using all of your cores when you run it...

I've uploaded a one-jar and I'm curious if you get the same results running this.  I'm using -server if that would make a difference.  http://filevo.com/p1nmijpo39x1.html

Comment: I'll download it and give it a shot. Let me tweak a few things on my end and see if it'll get parallel.

Comment: Sure enough I managed 530% CPU. After restarting my scala console, I also managed to max out my CPU there. My answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I guess I forgot to note that I'm using scala 2.9.1 as well.

Comment: I'm profiling it...it might be GC o.O your implementation loves memory...gigs of it.

Comment: I ran the script 10 times in a row (in a repl so it was the same jvm instance) and according to jconsole the total cpu time is 11 minutes but the total gc time is a mere 12 seconds (i have my max heap size set to 2 GB so it doesn't have to do much).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3814/discussion-between-lespea-and-xorlev)